# Computation of photon trajectory near a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, computational-physics

I've been given the task to represent the trajectory of a photon near a Schwarzschild Black hole. I've read the physics behind it, and I've derived the equation of photon orbit near a schwarzschild black hole, i.e.,

$$
\left(\frac{{\rm d}r}{{\rm d}\lambda}\right)^2=E^2 − \left(1−\frac{2M}{r}\right)\left(\frac{L}{r}\right)^2,
$$
and only the representation part is left. I'm not very good with coding and I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you've already found this question:

[Computing the path of photons near a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22986/computing-the-path-of-photons-near-a-black-hole/266747#266747)

In which you're given the following equation for the photon orbit:

$$ \left(\frac {dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2 = E^2 - \left(1 - \frac {2M}{r}\right) \frac {L^2}{r^2} $$

where the terms are defined in the link.

This tells you how the orbital radius varies with respect to the affine parameter. The angular coordinate also evolves according to

$$ \frac{d\phi}{d\lambda} = \frac{L}{r^2} $$

So the simplest way to numerically integrate these equations is to start off with a pair $(r_0,\phi_0)$, and then use the Euler forward method to advance 'time' by a small step $\Delta\lambda$:

\begin{align}
r_{n+1} &= r_n + \Delta\lambda \frac{dr}{d\lambda}\big|_n\\
\phi_{n+1} &= \phi_n + \Delta\lambda \frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\big|_n
\end{align}

where you evaluate the derivatives using the above equations. Then repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: I can easily evaluate the derivative, but how can I represent the orbit,(in 2D or 3D) that is my main problem. Calculation is not the trouble. How should I write a program to represent the orbit? and with which coding language?

Comment: @AakankshaAgarwal What do you mean by 'represent'? You have the $(r,\phi)$ coordinates, what more do you want?

Comment: How should I write a program to represent the orbit? and with which coding language?

Comment: I'll try once and get back to you if I face some problem.

Comment: @AakankshaAgarwal Oh well that's entirely up to you - any programming language will do. You will probably find [Python](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) to be the easiest if you're new to programming...

Comment: What about "E"? Is is constant? and what value should I take for "L"?

Comment: @AakankshaAgarwal $E$ will be constant. Its initial choice depends on the angle you want the photon to be travelling at. If you (presumably) want it to initially be tangential, then set $E=V(r_0)$, i.e. to the effective potential at your initial radius. $L$ will also be constant and will equal the $p_\phi$ coordinate of the four-momentum.

Comment: What should I take as the initial value of $r$ ? And then what logic should I follow to select the values of $M , L and E$?

Comment: @AakankshaAgarwal Firstly, you need to figure out the units. The above equations have assumed that $G=c=1$, so you need to pick consistent length and time units.